# Define MATLAB genetic algorithm cost function with more than one output (cost value)

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

Suppose that I want have more that one output in MATLAB R2016a genetic algorithm cost function. Finally I want extract these outputs beside best population and best obtained cost of algorithm (optimized outputs reporting). Can I have more than one output in cost function? We don't use these outputs for cost calculation of genetic algorithm. These outputs are only for final reporting. Suppose that we have this cost function:

```
function [cost_value, new_raw_data] = Cost_ANN_EA(selecter, raw_data1, naming)

%% some calculations of raw_data1

%% new_raw_data; %% new generated raw_data1 for cost calculation


    cost_value = xx;

end
```

I don't want process again `raw_data1` after optimization algorithm will find solution. I want extract processed `new_raw_data` from cost function and find best `new_raw_data` besides final best cost value of `ga` function. Anyway to do this?

Comment: Add some example code of how you use genetic algorithms in MATLAB including a cost function and an example of what extra output you would want it to have

Comment: @Dan. Question is revised.

Comment: The `ga` documentation states the fitness function should return a scalar value. Do you want to use your second output only for the last (optimised) parameter set, or for all steps in between? In the first case, just compute the second output after the `ga` algorithm is completed. In the second case you should somehow store the second output elsewhere, e.g. save it in a .mat file or use `assignin('base', ... , ... )` to store the output on the go in the main workspace.

Comment: @Erik. `raw_data1` is changing in iterations (genetic algorithm is optimizing this data set) so I want optimized structure of this data set in final step.

Comment: @user2991243 please include your call to the `ga` function or however you are acutlaly calling on the genetic algorithm. Is your cost function of the right form? Can it take three inputs like that?

Comment: Does your second output variable depend on the state in each iteration? If so, you can use and Output Function (see here: http://mathworks.com/help/gads/genetic-algorithm-options.html#f17837) to calculate it on every iteration. Your cost function then simply calculates cost and the output function does the rest.